# Identifying OEM amp Connectors

Tags: amplifier, connector, automotive

Can anyone help identify connector type for A & C below or suggest site/keywords I could use to narrow search?  I have sent inquiry to several sites selling automotive connectors and Googled extensively but no success :-(

[image]

---

Update for anyone else interested:  Contacted Metra directly and they have no solutions. Poured through Mouser and no plugs which match socket.

Comment: tends to be proprietary , plug to board-conn with two blade sizes, x pins, y spacing, keyed, interlocked, shrouded.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I could find.
https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=metra+harness

I leave the rest up to you.

Or call them direct http://metraonline.com

Comment: Thanks.  I did look at wiring harnesses for Hyundai 1st but unfortunately the system in Genesis model is produced by Lexicon and doesn't follow standard Hyundai configuration.  I was hoping to go different direction by figuring out manufacturer (assuming they are using mass-produced connector and not a custom variant).

Comment: probably 500 pc minimum order. How many k do you need?

Comment: Ouch, only need male/female for A & C.

Comment: go to audio jobber and beg for scraps

Comment: Did you mean auto jobber?  If not I'm not finding anything for "Audio Jobber"?

Comment: yes shops that do aftermarket audio auto installations